# Admin Menus - Name Menu different from first Submenu

Tags: php, admin, admin-menu, add-menu-page

I am creating a submenu with the following code:

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'jp_create_admin_pages' );

function jp_create_admin_pages()
{
    add_menu_page(
        'Members',
        'Members',
        'manage_options',
        'members',
        'jp_handle_admin_members');

    add_submenu_page(
        'members',
        'Membership Types',
        'Membership Types',
        'manage_options',
        'jp_handle_admin_membership_types');
}
```

This creates a custom menu called 'Members' with two sub-menus: 'Members' and 'Membership Types'.

I want to make it so that the first submenu is called 'All Members' instead of 'Members' (to mirror the built in menu types).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

The first menu item typically is the parent item and shares the name with that item, you can however manually update the entry directly in the `$submenu` variable, like so..

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'jp_create_admin_pages' );

function jp_create_admin_pages() {
    global $submenu;
    add_menu_page('Members','Members','manage_options','members','jp_handle_admin_members');
    add_submenu_page('members','Membership Types','Membership Types','manage_options','membership_types','jp_handle_admin_membership_types');
    $submenu['members'][0][0] = 'All Members';
}
```

That way your parent keeps the original name, whilst the first subitem has another.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Note, your `add_submenu_page` call was missing the callback(it's the 6th arg), i've added a menu slug and moved what i'd assume is your callback down to the 6th param.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing the `Menu title` to **'All Membership Types'**?

```
add_submenu_page(
        'members',
        'Membership Types',
        'All Membership Types',
        'manage_options',
        'jp_handle_admin_membership_types');
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page

Not sure if it's possible to do it any other way.

I know what you are trying to achieve, like when registering a [custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type). There is actually a field for `All Items` that's built into the labels array.

Comment: Unfortunately, this wouldn't solve the question, I think. The idea is to change the first submenu item so that the parent menu item is labeled "Members" and the first submenu item under that is labeled "All Members".